# Using Create-React-App, is there anyway to Inject/replace/append code into the index.html file during the build process like you can with grunt/gulp?

Tags: reactjs, asp.net, build, create-react-app, code-injection

Create-react-app creates an index.html file in the build folder, which I have finessed it to rename the file to index.aspx `(in package.json - "build": "react-scripts build && mv build/index.html build/index.aspx",)` because I need the application to run within a template on our server - which it does. However, I am currently having to past `<%@ Page language="c#" CodeBehind="index_fw2.aspx.cs" AutoEventWireup="false" Inherits="IMod.Web.V2.Index" %>` before the `<!doctype html>` in the new index.aspx file in order for the template to render on our server.

Is there anyway that I can have create-react-app inject this into the newly renamed index.aspx file or even before it's renamed from index.html **during the build process**? I have looked everywhere for a reference on this.

Comment: you can use `html-webpack-plugin` for that.

Comment: That looked promising, but I don't see where it allows you to append the html to the document. I see where it allows to to inject in the <head> or <body> tags, but this actually need to be place at the beginning of the document, before the <!doctype html> tag... Thanks though...

Comment: check this https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin/tree/master/examples/custom-insertion-position

Comment: I guess I'm not following, I appologize - I am very new to webpack, but I don't need to place anything in the head or body tags, I need to place it before the <!doctype html> - which I don't think qualifies as an actual tag... it's a declaration... that's why append document would be useful...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following solution worked for me. We don't need to use craco for this. Simply create an env variable using `env-cmd` and place it in your HTML code.

In Env File:

```
 REACT_APP_ASP_NET=<%@ Page language="c#" CodeBehind="index_fw2.aspx.cs" AutoEventWireup="false" Inherits="IMod.Web.V2.Index" %>
```

In HTML Page ( Simply place it on top of page):

```
  %REACT_APP_ASP_NET%
```

Answer (score 1):

You can insert what ever you want into your html file with webpack. In current example I'm using **html-webpack-plugin**.

**webpack.config.js**

```
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  ....
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './src/index.html', // Path to your index file
      some_variable: '<%@ Page language="c#" CodeBehind="index_fw2.aspx.cs" AutoEventWireup="false" Inherits="IMod.Web.V2.Index" %>', // 
    }),
  ],
};
```

And then insert a template variable into your index.html file:

```
<%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.some_variable %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
   ....
```

After you run build script, webpack will replace your template variable with defined in config file.

Comment: Okay Cool, giving this a shot, hoping this does not cause conflicts with create-react-app

Comment: So I installed html-webpack-plugin. I have also created a webpack.config.js file and placed in the code above using variable name aspxPrefix in place of some_variable. Create-React-App installs webpack: 
npm ls webpack
blueprint-wizard@0.1.0 /Users/tboswell/Documents/Repos/_Tony/blueprint-wizard
└─┬ react-scripts@3.2.0
  └── webpack@4.41.0

Comment: My webpack.config.js file looks like this:

`const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: './public/index.html',
            aspxPrefix: '<%@ Page language="c#" CodeBehind="index_fw2.aspx.cs" AutoEventWireup="false" Inherits="IMod.Web.V2.Index" %>',
            filename: './build/index.aspx' //relative to root of the application
        }),
   ],

};`

Comment: And I have place `<%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.aspxPrefix %>` into the index.html file located in the public folder, however, when I run build, it is neither renaming the file to .aspx nor is it replacing the variable....

Comment: Is there something in the configuration of create react app that I am missing?

Comment: As I understand it, create-react-app has its own webpack configuration (under node_modules/react-scripts/config) that you cannot alter unless you eject it. I'm very interested in the answer to this question because I'm trying to do a similar thing so you, but I don't see any way to change the default behaviour of create-react-app

Comment: @Andy - That was my understanding too... I mean, using the package.json, I can rename the file using node and adding the line in build after react-scripts runs
`"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build && mv build/index.html build/index.aspx",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },`

However, I'm not sure I can call another module here. And for whatever reason, Create-React-App is not even aware of HtmlWebpackPlugin being installed...

Answer (score 0):

Okay, So I figured this out. **Create-React-App installs its own version of Webpack** which it uses - this being said, it already has a **webpack.config.js** file it uses inside `node_modules/react-script/config/webpack.config.js`

So I found this file and searched for HtmlWebpackPlugin and found it at about line 585:

```js
 plugins: [
      // Generates an `index.html` file with the <script> injected.
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin(
        Object.assign(
          {},
          {
            inject: true,
            template: paths.appHtml,

            // Here I added my defined variable name aspxPrefix that is located in my template to be replaced - <%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.aspxPrefix %>

            aspxPrefix: '<%@ Page language="c#" CodeBehind="index_fw2.aspx.cs" AutoEventWireup="false" Inherits="IMod.Web.V2.Index" %>',

           // Then added the location and name I wanted the modified file to have here - in this case, I want it located in the build folder and renamed with .aspx

          filename: paths.appBuild+'/index.aspx'
          },
```

Man I hope this helps somebody, because I wasted about 3 hours of my day. And thanks @Satif for giving me the solution. Your solution worked, but I just needed to know where to place it in a Create-React-App produced environment.

Comment: Changing code in your node_module dependencies is **not** the way to go, those changes are only on your local machine, are not committed (at least should not be) and moreover, would be gone the moment this dependency is updated or reinstalled. If ejecting CRA is not for you, give [craco](https://github.com/gsoft-inc/craco/tree/master/packages/craco) a try

Comment: Whilst I agree that we can't edit that dependency's file, it was very helpful to know how and where this is happening. Thanks @Tony.